# proxy_http:error [pid 12216:tid 1348] [client 135.215.11.191:63376] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache, server

I am working on ROR(Ruby on rails) project and that application is hosted on **APACHE 2.4 server**.

My Application is running fine without fail but some times it is getting down. And I have to restart server to make it up.

I checked the error.log file in APACHE and found below lines that can explorer more to you.

**LOG**

```
[Tue Jul 26 12:34:43.837275 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 12216:tid 668] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.9+.
[Tue Jul 26 12:34:43.837275 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 12216:tid 668] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Tue Jul 26 12:34:43.880279 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12216:tid 668] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Jul 26 12:46:57.009585 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 12216:tid 1348] (OS 10061)No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.  : AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3020 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Tue Jul 26 12:46:57.009585 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 12216:tid 1348] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Tue Jul 26 12:46:57.009585 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 12216:tid 1348] [client 135.215.11.191:63376] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Please suggest something that I don't need to restart my server frequently. And my application runs for long time.